# how to bordered a single button on selected in list

Tags: list, flutter, select, border

I have a list of buttons,
I would like to select one of them and the red bordered appear onClick.
once click again, border disappear. How can I achieved that?
As far as I did, when I click it circle all the button in list at once.
please kindly teach me.

Comment: would you mind to share you code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will have to create a `stateful widget` for your button, that keeps track of if it should show the border or not. This is what it should look like:

```
class MyButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyButtonState createState() => _MyButtonState();

  final Widget child;
  final void Function() onPressed;
  final Key key;
  final Color buttonPrimaryColor, buttonOnPrimaryColor, borderColor;
  final double borderWidth;
  MyButton({
    @required this.child,
    this.onPressed,
    this.key,
    this.borderColor = Colors.red,
    this.buttonPrimaryColor,
    this.buttonOnPrimaryColor,
    this.borderWidth = 1.0,
  });
}

class _MyButtonState extends State<MyButton> {
  bool showBorder = false;
  void toggleShowBorder() => setState(() => showBorder = !showBorder);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      key: widget.key,
      onPressed: widget.onPressed == null
          ? null
          : () {
              toggleShowBorder();
              widget.onPressed();
            },
      child: widget.child,
      style: ButtonStyle(
        // If showBorder == true, we show a red border
        shape: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
          (_) => showBorder
              ? RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
                  side: BorderSide(
                    color: widget.borderColor,
                    width: widget.borderWidth,
                  ),
                )
              : RoundedRectangleBorder(),
        ),
      ).merge(
        ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          primary: widget.buttonPrimaryColor ??
              Theme.of(context).buttonTheme.colorScheme.primary,
          onPrimary: widget.buttonOnPrimaryColor ??
              Theme.of(context).buttonTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The usage is very simple:

```
MyButton(
  child: Text('Press me'),
  onPressed: () {},
),
```

If you want to change the button's color you can do it by passing in parameters:

```
MyButton(
  borderColor: Colors.amber,
  buttonPrimaryColor: Colors.white,
  buttonOnPrimaryColor: Colors.black,
  child: Text('Press me'),
  onPressed: () {},
),
```

Use `buttonPrimaryColor` for the button's background color
Use `buttonOnPrimaryColor` for the button's foreground color
Use `borderColor` for the button's border color (it is red by default)

You can also change the border width, using the `borderWidth` parameter, like this: (it is `1.0` by default)

```
MyButton(
  borderWidth: 4.0,
  child: Text('Press me'),
  onPressed: () {},
),
```

It would also be a good idea to pass in a `key` parameter since you are working
with a list of buttons, like this:

```
MyButton(
  key: Key('some unique key'),
  child: Text('Press me'),
  onPressed: () {},
),
```

The key should be a unique string.

Comment: Thanks you very much. Can't wait to try it out. I never thought of create abother buttons class and used it saperately! Thank you. :)

Comment: No problem, have a great day! :)